# how can I flatten a list to its values?

Tags: racket

I'd like to call `set-union` from a list of sets. How can I convert it into a form that `set-union` would take?

```
(define (return-set-list) (list (set 1) (set 2)))
(set-union (set) (return-set-list))
```

This returns an error for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`apply`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._apply%29%29)

```
(apply set-union (cons (set) (return-set-list)))
```